# How to create many single select inputs for a has_many association on simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, simple-form

I've created a form using Simple Form in Rails to create new tests.  My `Test` model has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with the `Tool` Model.

My code gets all tools and groups them into categories (a `category` is an attribute of a tool). It then creates a single select box for each category (as shown in the image).

```
- all_tools = Tool.all.group_by(&:category)
  - all_tools.each do |category|
    = f.association :tools,
      collection: category.last,
      label: category.first,
      label_method: lambda { |tool| "#{tool.name} (#{tool.description})"},
      input_html: { multiple: false }
```

[Many select boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2imrI.png)

When choosing a tool from each select box and submitting the form, I get the following error:

```
found unpermitted parameter: tool_ids
```

and the there's only one id currently being submitted for the `tool_ids` instead of an array of ids which I need.

I know this works when the boxes are `multiple` selects but I only want the user to be able to select one tool from each category and have it submit all tool_ids in an array similar to the way it would if the user was selecting them from a `multiple` select box.

So my question is, how can I use multiple single select boxes to submit an array of `tool_ids` in Simple Form?

EDIT: 
As requested, I've added the relevant code:

**tests_controller**:

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(test_params)
  @tools = Tool.all.select(:name).distinct
  if @test.save

    Activity.log(current_user, "Created test #{@test.id}")

    redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new, notice: 'Unable to save Test Details.'
  end
end

private

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(
    :date,
    :start_time,
    :description,
    :machine,
    :location,
    :feeder_screw_diameter,
    :notes,
    :user_id,
    :tool_ids => [],
    :powder_ids => []
  )
end
```

**Log output when submitting:**

```
Started POST "/tests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-08 13:24:52 +0100
Processing by TestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters:       {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"WKw+tQ1WKyxW7XZWCDvbvShCKnZ7iMY597P8eDGIvZEyis4ks7Mf4Lcu4vCf7q+fwtsReocmAlMGUrrhI4SgdQ==",
  "test"=>{"start_time(1i)"=>"2016",
  "start_time(2i)"=>"5",
  "start_time(3i)"=>"8",
  "start_time(4i)"=>"13",
  "start_time(5i)"=>"23",
  "description"=>"Test",
  "machine"=>"Some machine",
  "location"=>"Some Place",
  "feeder_screw_diameter"=>"15",
  "tool_ids"=>"21",
  "powder_ids"=>["", "3"],
  "user_id"=>"1",
  "date"=>"11-05-2016",
  "notes"=>"Some Notes"},
  "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:         
  Environment Monitored? false         
  API key set? true

ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: tool_ids):
  app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:201:in `test_params'
  app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:70:in `create'


  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (12.9ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (7.9ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (16.1ms)
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post the code for the controller and the log output for the post and form action.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill No problem - I've added it above.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It certainly was.  Which version of Rails are you using?  I've tried to reproduce this, and can't get that error.  One suggestion that I found was to change your `permit` to use `tool_ids => {}` instead of the array version, because that's more lenient.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1.  Thanks for the hint - I've tried using `tool-ids => {}` and it just ignores the paramater in that case.  This might be a stupid question but could it be because all the inputs have the same `trial_tool_ids` id on the page?  The paramater that the form posts (`"tool_ids"=>"21"`) is the id of the tool submitted in the last input box on the page for the tools.

Comment: It seems that you have 2 separate issues: a) getting tool_ids defined as a strong parameter for both scalar ("21") and array (["21","35]) values, and 2) defining multiple fields with the same name.  I'm focusing on (a) now.  When you say that it "ignores the parameter", does that mean that the `found unpermitted parameter: tool_ids ` error doesn't occur with `tool_ids => {}` as the strong parameter argument?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Firstly, I've worked out that it only submits the value of the last select box as a scalar (`"tool_ids"=>"21"`).   To answer your question, when using `tool_ids` on its own as a strong parameter, it adds the tool from the last select box to the join table for the association (`INSERT INTO "tools_tests"`).  This is what I want it to do for all the select boxes.  When using `tool_ids => []`, it throws the above error. When using `tool_ids => {}`, it still submits the scalar parameter of the last select box but it doesn't add it to the db.